# How can I mock a method which is not defined in the interface?

Tags: php, phpunit

In my php file I am using `Zend\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface`. I have bind this interface with `Zend\filesystem` cache. I have to unit test the main php file. Problem is **StorageInterface** does not define flush method. **Filesystem** have flush method from different interface.

In my unit testing I am trying to mock the **StorageInterface** but problem is it gives an error stating that flush is not defined. How can I stub the flush method?

Binding:

```php
$container->bindIf(
            "Zend\\Cache\\Storage\\StorageInterface",
            function () {
                $directoryPath = "/tmp/zend_report_cache";
                if (!file_exists($directoryPath) && !mkdir($directoryPath)) {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to create directory [directoryPath=$directoryPath]");
                }
                return \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory(array(
                    'adapter' => array(
                        'name' => 'filesystem',
                        'options' => array(
                            'cache_dir' => $directoryPath
                        ),
                    ),
                    'plugins' => array('serializer'),
                ));
            }
        );
```

Main.php (only showing relevant code

```php
use Zend\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface;

public function __destruct()
{
    $this->cache->flush();
}
```

unit test file

```php
private function getCacheMock()
    {
$cacheMock = $this->setMethods(['execute'])->createMock(StorageInterface::class);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(0))->method('setItem')->with(CsvReport::HEADER_CACHE_KEY, []);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(1))->method('getItem')->with(CsvReport::HEADER_CACHE_KEY)->willReturn([]);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(2))->method('setItem')->with(CsvReport::HEADER_CACHE_KEY, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(3))->method('setItem')->with(0, $this->getMockRow(0));
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(4))->method('getItem')->with(CsvReport::HEADER_CACHE_KEY)->willReturn(['key1', 'key2', 'key3']);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(5))->method('setItem')->with(CsvReport::HEADER_CACHE_KEY, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(6))->method('setItem')->with(1, $this->getMockRow(1));
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(7))->method('getItem')->with(CsvReport::HEADER_CACHE_KEY)->willReturn(['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(8))->method('setItem')->with(CsvReport::HEADER_CACHE_KEY, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']);
        $cacheMock->expects($this->at(9))->method('setItem')->with(2, $this->getMockRow(2));
        return $cacheMock;
    }
```

Error: Trying to configure method "flush" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

Comment: You can always define a test stub and use or mock that instead of your interface

Comment: As the method is undefined, it can not be mocked/configured by the Phpunit mock-builder. But as Robbie Averill has already commented, you can write the stub your own with the flush method. But you could also just mock one of the existing classes that fulfill the interface you want to test and just have the flush method.